# When trying to read #NAME? Value from excel to a string gives Type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which reads a description string from excel and finds out the particular string is present in the data or not.

Sometimes the input file might contain a value like #NAME? in the cell. When the macro reaches this cell its just gives error type mismatch Run time error 13 on the following line.

I just wanted to ignore this line and continue the with the next line. How I should I give a validation (if). I'm using a 'do- loop until' for the loop. descriptionString is a string variable.

```
descriptionString = currentwrkbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use IsError, something like so

`if iserror(currentwrkbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value))....`

Comment: ++ This is the easiest way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

you may want to iterate through valid cells only using [`SpecialCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object, that allows you to filter a range returning a range with *"all the cells that match the specified type and value"*

for instance

```
myRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
```

will return `myRange` cells containing constant (i.e. not resulting from formulas) text values only

so that a possible snippet for your purposes could be the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim currentwrkbk As Workbook
    Dim descriptionString As String

    With currentwrkbk.Worksheets(1) 
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through text values of column "A" only

            descriptionString = cell.value

        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: wow haven't see SpecialCells for 20 years.  Nice little feature.

Answer (score 2):

@Nathan_Sav has alredy given you one option. Here is another.

```
If Not CVErr(currentwrkbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value) = CVErr("2029") Then _
descriptionString = currentwrkbk.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Here is the rest of the list

```
2007 returns a #DIV/0! error.
2042 returns a #N/A error.
2029 returns a #NAME? error.
2000 returns a #NULL! error.
2036 returns a #NUM! error.
2023 returns a #REF! error.
2015 returns a #VALUE! error.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Siddharth. I have taken Nathan's method for this problem. But i guess your answer is going to solve another issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use IsError along with Clng to convert to an error code and test for that

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()


    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("i13")
    '* i creat a #NAME here
    rng.Formula = "=namenoexist"

    Debug.Assert IsHashName(rng)


End Sub


Function IsHashName(ByVal rng As Excel.Range) As Boolean
    Debug.Assert Not rng Is Nothing
    Debug.Assert rng.Rows.Count = 1
    Debug.Assert rng.Columns.Count = 1

    Dim v As Variant
    v = rng.Value2
    '*So test for IsError and then cast to a long and test for 2029 to see if i
    If IsError(v) Then
        If CLng(v) = 2029 Then
            IsHashName = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```